# property does not exist error on Typescript class

Tags: typescript

When I attempt to compile the following typescript class I get the error:

```
"use strict";
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

const remote: string = 'http://localhost:3000';
export class ApiEndpoint {
  public contentHeader: Headers = new Headers({"Content-Type": "application/json"});

  constructor(private _http: Http) {}

  static signup(payload) {
    let url = `${remote}/auth/signup`;
    return this._http.post(url, JSON.stringify(payload), {headers: this.contentHeader});
  }

  static checkUsername(username) {
    let url = `${remote}/auth/checkUsername/${username}`;
    return this._http.get(url);
  }

}
```

Errors:

```
17): Error TS2339: Property '_http' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiEndpoint'.
TypeScript error:(12,73): Error TS2339: Property 'contentHeader' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiEndpoint'.
TypeScript error: /(17,17): Error TS2339: Property '_http' does not exist on type 'typeof ApiEndpoint'.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared two instance members (`_http`, `contentHeader`) and then tried to access them from a static method. Static methods obviously can't see instance members (because *which* instance?).

I think you probably just want to remove `static` from those methods.